# Growth bounds for the exponential of an operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, matrix-exponential

Let $X$ be a complex Banach space and $A:X \to X$ a compact operator. It spectrum is the set $\sigma(A)=\lbrace \lambda \in \mathbb{C}, \  A-\lambda I \text{ is not invertible}\rbrace$. Let $L=\sup\lbrace re(\lambda), \lambda \in \sigma(A)\rbrace$.

Let $e^A$ denote its exponential operator, defined by the series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{K^n}{n!}.$$

It is true, in the finite dimensional case, that if $L< 0$, then $$\Vert e^{tA}\Vert \xrightarrow{t \to \infty}{} 0.$$

**Is it also true in the general case?**

Sketch of a proof of the finite-dimensional case:

Let's prove it for $(\mathbb{R}^n, \Vert \ \Vert_{\infty})$ (we'll omit the subscript $\infty$). First let's recall that $$\Vert M \Vert =\max_{1\leq i \leq n}\lbrace \sum_{j=1}^{n}\vert a_{ij}\vert \rbrace.$$ In particular $\Vert \operatorname{diag}(d_1,d_2,...,d_n)\Vert\leq max\lbrace \vert d_i \vert \rbrace$.

Let's asume $A$ can be writen in Jordan form $A=C(N+D)C^{-1}$ with $N$ nilpotent and  $D$ diagonal. Then, $$e^{tA}=Ce^{tN}e^{tD}C=CG(t)H(t)C.$$The matrix $G(t)$ has polynomials in $t$ in its entries, so $\Vert G(t) \Vert=g(t)$, with $g(t)$ a real valued function of polynomial order in $\infty$. The matrix $H(t)=\operatorname{diag}(e^{t\lambda_1},...,e^{t\lambda_n})$, so $\Vert H(t) \Vert\leq \max\lbrace\vert e^{t\lambda_i} \vert\rbrace=\max\lbrace e^{t \ re(\lambda_i)} \rbrace=e^{tL}$. So, if $L<0$, 
$$\Vert e^{tA} \Vert \leq \Vert C \Vert p(t) e^{tL} \Vert C^{-1} \Vert \xrightarrow{t \to \infty} 0.$$

There are several problems in the infinite-dimensional case to adapt this proof:
there is no Jordan form, the eigenvalues are not necessarily associated with eigenvectors. There is an extra issue: informally, even if we had some sort of representation, the  $g(t)$ factor would not be a finite degree polynomial and could outweigh the $e^{tL}$ term.

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow! This is even true if $A$ is not compact but merely bounded. It is, for instance, a consequence of the spectral mapping theorem for the holomorphic functional calculus.

Comment: Hi, to continue the comment of Jochen, use Cauchy integral formula instead of power series to represent the exponential function.